# the number is not added, but adjusted Redux React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a problem. When I enter a number into the input and click on the button, I want to perform actions. Withdraw money from the counter or add it to the counter. For this I wrote a state:

```
const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case "ADD_CASH":
            return {...state, cash: state.cash + action.payload}
        case "GET_CASH":
            return {...state, cash: state.cash - action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }

}
const store = createStore(reducer)
```

Now you need to write events, I did it like this:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const cash = useSelector(state => state.cash)
  const [handleValue, setHandleValue] = useState(0)



  function addCash(){
    dispatch({type: "ADD_CASH", payload: handleValue})
  }
  function getCash(){
    dispatch({type: "GET_CASH", payload: handleValue})
  }
  function handleChange(event){

    setHandleValue(event.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <h1>{cash}</h1>
      <input onChange={handleChange} value={handleValue}/>
      <button onClick={addCash}>Добавить денег</button>
      <button onClick={getCash}>Снять денег</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please help me, I think this would not happen on the typescript
It happens:
[image]

Comment: Use `setHandleValue(+event.target.value)`. This has nothing to do with TypeScript.

Comment: I disagree, this - passing a string to something that expects a number - is exactly the kind of common mistake Typescript won't allow you to make.

Comment: Generally, please also be aware that you are using an extremely (pre-2019) style of Redux here. Modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES or immutable reducer logic. I would highly recommend you to follow [the official Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) as modern Redux code is a lot less code and more readable.